# Unix brace expansion within find command

Tags: linux, shell, find, brace-expansion

This is working fine:

```
$ echo email_{ldn,nyk,asp}.log
```

Similarly, I wanted to find filenames which differ slightly:

```
$ find ~ -type f -name email_{ldn,nyk,asp}.log
```

But above command results in error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: email_nyk.log
```

Any help on brace expansions within find command will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your OS? Do you have GNU `find`?

Comment: I'm using Linux 2.6.32 x86 64 GNU version.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification.

Comment: For anyone wants confirm, yes tilde `~` is to search from $HOME directory.

Answer (score 6):

The error message results from the expansion of the pattern by your shell.

Assuming you have the files `email_ldn.log`, `email_nyk.log` and `email_asp.log` in your current directory, your command

```
find ~ -type f -name email_{ldn,nyk,asp}.log
```

will be expanded to

```
find ~ -type f -name email_ldn.log email_nyk.log email_asp.log
```

which results in the error message.

To prevent the expansion of a pattern by the shell you have to quote the pattern. Unfortunately, `find` doesn't support patterns with a list of alternatives in braces, so using this pattern with `find` will **not** work as you might expect.

```
find ~ -type f -name "email_{ldn,nyk,asp}.log" # Does not work as intended.
find ~ -type f -name "email_*.log" # This would work, but matches other files as well.
```

If you have GNU find, you could use a regular expression instead.

```
find ~ -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/email_(ldn|nyk|asp).log"
```

Comment: Thanks Bodo for such a nice explanation.

Comment: @JamesBond If this answers your question you could accept the answer by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

Brace expansion is *not* the way to do this sort of thing, and `eval` is evil, but you could do:

```
eval find ~ -type f -and \\\( -false "-or -name "email_{ldn,nyk,asp}.log \\\)
```

The main idea is that `-name email_ldn.log email_nyk.log email_asp.log` does  not work, because you want the expression to be `-name email_ldn.log -or -name email_nyk.log -or -name email_asp.log`, so you create that expression with the brace expansion.  But then `find` receives `-or -name email_???.log` as a single argument instead of 3 arguments, so you need to force word splitting with `eval`.  Overall, a nasty, ugly solution.

Comment: Instead of eval, xargs will be much more suited in this type of implementation. Please see my next comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all files with one prefix you can use this command:

`find ~ -type f -name "email_*.log"`

In this situation you don't need to use braces. Don't forget to put `"` (quotes) before and after the pattern of the name.

`find` doesn't support braces to set alternatives, like the shell does. So, if you want to find specific files, you can do this in 2 steps: first find all files with 'email' prefix and then grep for specific files. Try this:
`find ~ -type f -name "email*" | egrep "email_(ldn|asp|nyk).log"`

Comment: This is going to match other files beside *.ldn.log or *.nyk.log or *.asp.log

Comment: So, you can do this in 2 steps: first you can find all files with 'email' prefix and then grep for specyfic files. Try this: `find ~ -type f -name "email*" | egrep "email_(ldn|asp|nyk).log"`

Find doesn't support braces to set alternatives, like echo command.

Comment: Thanks @Mikolaj for the responses, but I latter realized this can be done alternatively using xargs (I've posted it in answers section)

Answer (score -1):

It was realized eventually during the conquest, some of you have suggested using `eval`, but I think it would better to use `xargs` :

As the aim is to find files matching the brace expansion and execute few command thereafter, so `xargs` suites this purpose nicely.

`$ ls ~/email_{ldn,nyk,asp}.log | xargs -I %% sh -c 'chomd 644 %% && cp -arf %% ~/feed_dir'`